# JavaScript reverse DNS look-up

Tags: javascript, dns, reverse-dns

Is there a way to display the reverse DNS entry for someone visiting your page using only JavaScript? Or is the only way to do an AJAX request to a server that can do it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use sAjax for this. Make a request with javascript and than execute your php function and use callback for display result.